# What is the point of AsyncTimeout action filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await

Trying to decrease the timeout of a given operation of my controller (let's say it's Index) I annotated it with [AsyncTimeout(5000)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.asynctimeoutattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).
Inside that method, the first line is `await Task.Delay(10000)`.
I published that code to azure, guaranteeing that there's no `debug="true"` but even so, the request runs for 11-13 sec... so, in my opinion that is not how it's supposed to be used...

So, where should i use this attribute?

Details:
Using .net 4.7 (compilation and runtime) and latests asp.net mvc (5.2.3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look to use the overload of Task.Delay that accepts the CancellationToken.  The AsyncTimeout will trigger the cancellation in that case.  Your code posted is not using a CancellationToken so I wouldn't expect anything different to happen without it.

UPDATE-  Quick demo building on your question.  This should throw a TaskCanceledException in about 5 seconds instead of waiting for the Task.Delay call of 15 seconds.

```
[AsyncTimeout(5000)]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Stopwatch cancellationTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    try
    {                
        await Task.Delay(15000, cancellationToken);
        cancellationTimer.Stop();
        return View();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         cancellationTimer.Stop();
         Debug.WriteLine($"Elapsed Time {cancellationTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
         throw (e);
    }            
}
```

Comment: what happens if my code is currently on a long calculation (huge loop or something like that)? could you post a usage sample pls? (i'll be looking online for one too...)